# How to get information about UWP app?

Tags: windows-10, uwp

How can I get information about an UWP application on Windows 10 from another application?

As a minimum, I am interested in application name and default tile. Then, I would like to be able to learn as much as possible, of course.

Some UWP apps can be linked to an EXE. That is, their main window is created by an EXE. This helps. At least, I know the location of "resource.pri", which presumably can be read.

But, there are apps which do not have EXE, and "hosted" by wwahost.exe instead. These are black boxes to me. Is there any way to know what is inside?

I would appreciate any hints.
Thanks

Comment: what's your purpose?

Comment: My purpose is getting information, ID, whatever.

Comment: With regular desktop app, I can find EXE name.
EXE has version information, default icon.
If something does not have version info (ID), it also means something (something bad, usually).
I want to know what is working on my computer.
Also, I need it for my system utility.
With the same purpose - it shows what is going on on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but very different than what we do for desktop apps. I can share you the possible solution but there are some security issues, so I suggest you contact Microsoft to get a better way(maybe open some APIs for this kind of information) ensure your users have a safe system.

Here is what we need to do to get these information.

1. Enum WWAHost process.
2. You can enum "File type" items loaded into WWAHost, and find the one which is in this format: "***C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\xxxx***". When you view the app in Task Manager and view its properties, you will find it is a folder property windows. And you can also use Process Explorer to check the WWAHost process, and you will find the folder format I mentioned.
3. (***Security Issue***) To get the package name, version and more information, you have to access the folder I mentioned above. By reading the AppxManifest and dumping the resource.pri by using "makepri dump" and reading the generated resource.pri.xml, you will be able to get many information. **But**, we have to use special way to get access to the windowsapps folder and it will raise security risk to your users' OS(and maybe other issues). But if it is for your personal use, it's OK.

Comment: "Enum file type items loaded into WWAHost"...
Do you mean EnumProcessModules??

Ok. I do not know how to "enum file type items", but I know how to enum process modules, and this is what I did.
First attempt was success. I have found couple of WINMD files, and their location clearly indicated the app location.

Next attempt was a failure. No WINMD files at all. None of the process DLLs pointed to the app location.

That is, thank you for the suggestion. I did not think about it myself. It can help, but is not reliable.

Comment: No. I mean enum the file handle. there is a very old sample on codeproject but it works. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18975/Listing-Used-Files .